# How to create ServiceBase class using System.Reflection

Tags: c#, service, system.reflection

I want to create a service installer in my project, and I have several serviceBase classes in my project. This is the main program code:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] temp = ConfigurationUtils.ReadSetting("XServices").Split(',');
        string serviceNamespace = ConfigurationUtils.ReadSetting("Services Namespace");
        ServiceBase[] servicesToRun;// = new ServiceBase[temp.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length;i++ )
        {
            Type typeService = Type.GetType(serviceNamespace + "." + temp[i]);
            servicesToRun[i] = (ServiceBase) Activator.CreateInstance(typeService, true);
        }

        ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
    }
}
```

In this program I read the class (can be more than one class) that I want to create from app.config. And then I use Reflection to create the service (based on the app.config).
I use app.config to make the services that I want to add configurable.

Then, I can build my project and install the service. But, when I start my service, it can't load my service class.
I think it is because the class that I just created cannot behave as my service class.

This is my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
          <add key="log_directory_performancelog" value="C:\Wcms\Modules\XPerformance\Data\" />
          <add key="log_directory_website_monitoring" value="C:\Wcms\Modules\XWebsiteMonitoring\Data\"/>
          <add key="config_path_performance" value="C:\Program Files\Wcms\XLogClient\config.txt" />
          <add key="config_path_website_monitoring" value="C:\Program Files\Wcms\XLogClient\website.monitor.config.txt" />
          <add key="XServices" value="XLogClientPerformance,XLogClientWebsiteMonitoring" />
          <add key="Services Namespace" value="XLog.Client" />
          <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please post your App.config content.

Comment: How service type looks like? Intercept with `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(typeService);`.

Comment: Are your services in the currently executing assembly? If not then you should first load the assembly in which your services are and then try to load the type.

Comment: @abatishchev the app.config just added. My service to get the performance from CPU and website uptime from several url

Comment: @shashwat12 what do you mean executing assembly? Sorry, just new in .net

Comment: The assembly which has the code which is currently executing is called the Executing Assembly. For example if you have 2 assemblies one `.exe` and one `.dll` then the code which will be running in any of the two assemblies will be the current executing assembly.

Comment: Specify fully qualified type name, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx